# Finding the basis for an intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $U_1, U_2$ have the following bases, $\mathcal{B}_1$,$\mathcal{B}_2$ respectively:

$\mathcal{B}_1$ = $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$, $\mathcal{B}_2$ = $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 3\\1\\7\\3 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -3\\2\\-5\\-1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$,

I want to find the basis for $U_1 \cap U_2$.

From previous posts, I gather that I need to row-reduce the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \mathcal{B}_1 | -\mathcal{B}_2 \end{bmatrix}$ which yields:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&-3&0\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Clearly the third column is not linearly independent. I got lost after that and do not know what to do. Is it true that the basis for $U_1 \cap U_2$ is the first, second, and fourth columns since they are linearly independent?

Comment: $U_1 \cap U_2$ is a subspace of $U_1$ and of $U_2$. Therefore its dimension cannot exceed the dimension of $U_1$ or of $U_2$, and in particular it can't be $3$.

Comment: I know $dim(U_1 \cap U_2) = dim(U_1) +dim(U_2) -dim(U_1 +U_2) = 2+2-2 = 2$. That is why I asked

Comment: Are you sure about that? The reduced matrix says something different about $\dim(U_1+U_2)$.

Comment: Well. I might be wrong. It depends on what is meant by $U_1 +U_2$. I thought it is adding the two bases elementwise. We get  two independent columns when we row reduce it.

Comment: $dim(U_1 + U_2) = 3$, not $2$. (You can conclude this from the fact $[\mathcal B_1 | -\mathcal B_2]$ has three linearly independent columns.) So $dim(U_1 \cap U_2) = 1$.

Comment: So $U_1 +U_2$ is not adding the vectors elementwise? it is stacking the bases into one matrix and finding their dim?

Comment: $U_1+U_2$ is the set of all sums $v+w$ with $v\in U_1$ and $w\in U_2$. In other words, the space spanned by $\mathcal B_1\cup\mathcal B_2$.

Comment: From the row-reduced form, you can see at a glance that column 3 is a linear combination of the first two columns, therefore the corresponding column in $[\mathcal B_1 | \mathcal B_2]$ is in $U_1$ and $U_2$. (Why?)

Comment: So you are saying that column 3 is the basis for the intersection? Is it because the other columns somehow could form a linear combination that results in col 3? I am still not sure why.

Comment: I am also not sure of what is the purpose/rationale of row reducing $[\mathcal{B}_1 | - \mathcal{B}_2]$. Why is there a negative sign?